# Unable to pass parameters on a xml file using Cucumber and TestNG

Tags: java, cucumber, testng, dataprovider, testng.xml

I've been having a hard time trying to pass parameters on a xml file using TestNG and Cucumber setup. The test does run in parallel but parameters are not being passed, returns null. According to SmartBear documentation, `@Parameters` should work but it doesn't. Below is a snippet of the code. Was wondering if anyone came across this issue.

**POM**

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        <configuration>
        <suiteXmlFiles>
    <file>src/test/resources/testng.xml</file>
        </suiteXmlFiles>
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                    <value>2</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
```

**XML_FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="2" name="Suite" parallel="tests">
  <test name="Chrome">
  <parameter name="os" value="Mac OSX 10.14"/>
  <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="test.java.com.cucumber.TestRunner"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <test name="Firefox">
  <parameter name="os" value="Mac OSX 10.14"/>
  <parameter name="browser" value="ff"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="test.java.com.cucumber.TestRunner"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

**TESTRUNNER**

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:features", glue = "test.java.com.step_definitions", tags = "@signin")
public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

**METHOD WHERE PARAMETER WILL BE PASSED**

```
 @BeforeClass
 @Parameters(value={"os","browser"})
 public DesiredCapabilities CBT_ChromeDesiredCap(String os, String browser){     
    HashMap<String, String> cbtoptions = new HashMap<String, String>();   
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setCapability("name", "Demo"); 
    caps.setCapability("os", os);
    caps.setCapability("browser", browser);
    caps.setCapability("version", "72");
    caps.setCapability("screenResolution", "1366x768");
    caps.setCapability("record_network", "false");  
    caps.setCapability("cbt:options", cbtoptions);
    return caps;            
}
```

SmartBear Documentation
https://support.smartbear.com/crossbrowsertesting/docs/automated-testing/parallel-testing.html

Cucumber Documentation
https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/

If you need more info please leave a comment and Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve it with the below solution.

```
Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("browser")
```